# Embeddable C++ HTTPS server library?

Tags: open-source, library, http

### tl;dr;

I'm looking for an HTTP/HTTPS library that can easily be embedded into other programs.

### What I'm trying to do

The use case I need it for is to use it for monitoring, debugging and otherwise accessing a program that is primarily running for other reasons. That is, being an HTTP server is a secondary aspect of the program.

### Requirements and nice to haves

The most important things I'm looking for is that it:

- Be OOS (permissive) or public domain licenced.
- Support HTTPS
- Not be "overly-opinionated". That it imposes as few constraints as possible (architecture, OS, etc.) on other, more primary, parts of the binary.

After that, properties I'd like to get (in no particular order):

- SPDY, WebSockets, etc. support, particularly if they only get linked in if I use them.
- Small binary footprint.
- Small source footprint.
- Low run-time overhead.
- Few dependencies and no overly broad ones (a single purpose library like OpenSSL is acceptable, a general purpose one like Boost is undesirable).
- Composable (as in it being easy for request handlers to lay claim to paths without much global coordination).
- Helpers for defining RESTful APIs and the like would be a minor plus, but only as long as the HTTP sever is agnostics to their use. They should be no more a part of the core server than my custom handler that returns arbitrary bytes.
- Usable for a "primarily a web server" project. (Why learn two different systems?)
- Support for building under [Bazel](https://bazel.build/), or at least not have an overly complex build.

I don't necessarily expect to get *all* of that, but I'd like as many as practical, or at least have some idea how different options stack up for those.

---

### Know non-results

Googleing has found a number of HTTP server libraries, but so far they have all failed the above criteria in one way or another:

- Many depend on Boost or a heavy weight dependency that may not otherwise be needed.
- [Some](https://pocoproject.org/docs/00100-GuidedTour.html) are built into large frameworks that expect to be the basis of the project.
- Others seem to be intended for projects that are first and foremost an HTTP server and seem to require specific architectural choices.
- Others only support Windows (if I can't get OS portability, then I need Linux fist.)

---

An example of the type of low-impact usage that I'd like to see:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  auto args = some_flags_lib::ParseCommandLine(argc, argv);

  HttpServer srv(HttpServerOptions{.port = port});

  some_lib::DebugWidget dgb{&srv};
  StatusWidget status{&srv};
  third_party::MonitoringWidget mon{&srv};

  srv.Start();

  auto exit_code = DoTheMainThing(args, &status);

  src.Stop();

  return exit_code;
}
```

---

*Edit:* Libraries I've seen suggested in places or found on my own, and why they are less than ideal (not necessarily unacceptable, but I'm still hoping for something better):

- [Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html): It's part of Boost (which is a rather widely scoped dependency which is not acceptable in some applications/users) and makes a big point about how it's built on a specific threading architecture.
- [libmicrohttpd](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/): C (not C++) and LGPL (if you want TLS) which again makes it unsuited for some applications/users.
- [libhttpserver](https://github.com/etr/libhttpserver): C++ (good) but built on libmicrohttpd (so LGPL, see above) and claims an explicit focus on REST (suggesting it assume a semantic model, or why say anything, maybe making it opinionated? That said, I'm not yet seeing anything that goes beyond just a generic HTTP server so maybe not, but then way does it mention REST at all?).
- [Http.Sys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-api-start-page): Windows only.